# Images resolve on one WPF window but not on the second

Tags: wpf, xaml, embedded-resource

I have some images in a Images folder in my WPF Project. They resolve just fine on my MainWindow.xaml window but when I reference the same images on a second window I get the error that VS cannot find the JPG file I am referencing. Seems like the systems is looking for the file in my C:\ProgramFiles\ directory. What is the difference in MainWindow.xaml and my second window?

I tried re-building the solution and re-entering the path and nothing seemed to help

Image References:

```
 <UniformGrid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\black-diamond-plate.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="Tile" Opacity=".25"/>
           </UniformGrid.Background>
    <UniformGrid.Background>
```

MainWindow.xaml The image can be referenced here.

```
<Window x:Class="QCast.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QCast"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="home" Height="450" Width="800" WindowState="Maximized" Background="#FF313030" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SteelBrush.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonnTemplates.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Image:

```
   </UniformGrid>
    <UniformGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
        <UniformGrid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\black-diamond-plate.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="Tile" Opacity=".25"/>
        </UniformGrid.Background>
```

wRawMatEntry.xaml (Here's where the image cannot be found)

```
<Window x:Class="QCast.Windows.RawMatEntry"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QCast.Windows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="RawMatEntry" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#FF313030" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="SteelBrush.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonnTemplates.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Image reference:

```
 </UniformGrid>
    <UniformGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
        <UniformGrid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\black-diamond-plate.jpg"  Stretch="UniformToFill" TileMode="Tile" Opacity=".25"/>
           </UniformGrid.Background>
        <Grid>
```

Comment: This question is ridiculously funny. How can anybody tell the difference of something that is not there? Compare nothing to nothing? I think you forgot to post the code for comparison. Make sure the Build Action for the image resource is set to _Resource._

Comment: Check the Build Action of the image. Also it looks like your `RawMatEntry` window is in a different namespace. If this namespace maps to a different folder then adjust your specified file path to it. E.g., path could be _"\..\Images\black-diamond-plate.jpg"_ where _.._ moves one directory toward the root (one folder up).

Answer (score -1):

I changed the path from

```
 "Images\black-diamond-plate.jpg"
```

to:

```
"\Images\black-diamond-plate.jpg"
```

because my Window was in subfolder of the so I had to reference the project itself project adn then it worked